# Is possibile to manage webviews transitions from javascript?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova, titanium, trigger.io

The main concept is that the Javascript *inside* webview can control the transitions/animations between another webview.

For example: An user clicks on a link and the Native container do the transition to the Webview with the new page (like JQuery Mobile, but the transitions are NATIVE).

For a quick reminder:

- Phonegap: One webview and an API for storage/geolocation/ecc.. NO ANIMATIONS.
- Titanium: You write in javascript the native components of the app. You have all types of animations... But it is too much complicated....
- Trigger.io: Same of Titanium (?)

I wonder if there are some projects that expose some methods that allows to manage more webviews (and its transitions) at once by the javascript inside webview.

Comment: [Phonegap (with jQUeryUI for mobile)](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html) and [Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Animation) support this, both are trivial to use especially compared to the native approach.

Comment: I have tried Phonegap + jquery mobile. But it was is full of flickering (especially in Android). The idea is to delegate the native container to do all the heavy graphic stuff.

Comment: If you want to have the native do the work then I would strongly suggest Titanium, its very stable, and since you already can write JavaScript, very easy to learn.

Comment: The transition to Trigger.io's modal views is fully native - see http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/features/modal.html#forge-modal

Comment: Ok, but afk Trigger.io manage a single webview. Modal webview are very handly, but if you want do a native transition to another full page ?